# How to embed HTML code in the laravel blade template?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, embed, code-snippets

I am trying to built a embed HTML system in where anyone can copy and paste code snippet in his website to display that.For this I have written requied code in the jquery section . I want to pass that code to a specific div so that that code is run as source code.

jquery part :

```
 $(document).on("click", "#embedLink", function () {
    var textArea=$("#textArea");
    var url = $('#headerInput').val();
    $("#framInput").val(url);
    var iframe =document.getElementById('ifrm');
    var html= '<iframe id="ifrm" src="'+url+'"width="100%" height="600"    frameborder="0"disable></iframe>';
    textArea.append(html);
    
});
```

blade template:

```
<div name="" id="textArea">
               
         </div>
```

I want to pass the html value in the div(id="textArea") element.And then I want to show like that....

```
<iframe id="ifrm" src="'+url+'"width="100%" height="600"    frameborder="0"disable></iframe>
```

How can do that?

Comment: Are you trying to get a url from user input and show that page in an iframe?

Answer (score 1):

You may try this way

```
textArea.append("<iframe id=\"ifrm\" src="+url+" style=\"width: 100%; height: 600;\" frameborder=\"0\" disable></iframe>");
```

Comment: this not working .The form is open in the iframe for the url

Answer (score 1):

This question is mine.At last I found the answer.
I have solved that passing the code as text.

I have solved the problem replacing it..

```
textArea.append(html);
```

by the following

```
textArea.text(html);
```